# ajax post send is not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm  having problem how to solve ajax post in codeigniter. GET method is working well but when I changed it to post, it is no longer working. I observed that when I disabled my  csrf_protection in config file, it is working, but when I enabled it, it is NOT WORKING. I want to use csrf_protection enabled while post method is working. Can anybody help me? Thanks..

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){  
  $('#submit').click(function(event) {  
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/common/test',
        data: {  
            <?php if ($this->config->item('csrf_protection') === true) : ?>
                post_data.<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?> = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>' 
            <?php endif ?>
        },
        success: function(response) {
            alert(response);
          }
      }); 
      return false; 
   });
});
  </script>  
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
 <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
```

On my Controller

```
  <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Common extends CI_Controller {

     function test(){ 
      echo 'test';
    }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery expects the headers to not be default HTTP headers. you need to change the headers of content-type i believe to match your output. See the attached documentation for how to use codeigniters output class to do this. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/output.html